# Missing partial, but the file is there with the underscore in the name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a partial view called _footer.html.erb (I created only this file manually) in my app/views/layouts folder.
In my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file, I have:

```
    <%= render 'layouts/_footer.html.erb' %>
```

When I open the page, I get the following error:

```
Missing partial layouts/_footer.html.erb with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "D:/rails/TestApp/app/views"
```

I've made some research and, as far as I understood, the only requirement is the underscore before the name.
Did I miss something? I am following [this tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-google-analytics.html)

Comment: Rails tries to be indirect and make you memorize little idiot tricks like a dog - so you put the underscore in the filename, but then must take it away when you refer to it.  Even then, it may say it doesn't find it while saying it looked right where it is, for some other "magic" reason.  Make sure your partial ends in "html.erb" for example.  It won't just load what you tell it to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note the underscore and file extension are dropped from the filename _footer.html.erb.

Try this:

```
 <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
```

[see more here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: Jackpot! Because both answers were at the same time, I'm marking this one as the corret one due to the extra info on the external link

Answer (score 5):

You can give a try with `<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>` as when using partials you dont use '_' symbol ..you just render it using its name